# SQL Server to Word/Excel/PDF

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

How can I export records from SQL Server to Word Excel and PDF file.
Is this possible?
Any help is too much appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: If you are after displaying the result set of your query / SP then I would recommend to have a look into SSRS / Report Builder which come for free with SQL Server

Comment: there are many options .Searching for this term "sql server to excel" yields many results.please try narrowing down the  problem

Comment: Basically the requirements is to show it using a datatable in html with pagination. Also it doesn't load all records from the table into that datatable.I can only export the current page with 10 rows, that is why i am seeking for other options to export all.

Comment: Are you looking to do this directly from SQL Management Studio, write an app in C# or some other approach? A little more information will go a long way towards getting the answer that you're after....